# How to trim the characters to a specified length using lpad in SPARK-SQL

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
spark.sql("select case when length(medicare)>0 then lpad(med,13,'0') else '' end as med from input").show(false)
```

In the above query I'm able to trim the characters to a specified length but what is the procedure to get the characters to a specified length with spaces before that.

sample input:          1234(10 spaces plus 1234)
sample output:         1234(9 spaces plus 1234)

Whatever the input is it should trim to 13 characters.

sample input:          1234567890123(10 spaces plus 1234567890123)
sample output:1234567890123(13 characters)

Please help me out on this...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the right-most 13 spaces and pad that to 13:

```
select lpad(right(medicare, 13), 13, ' ')
```

The `right()` function is just to handle the case where `medicare` might have more than 13 characters.

EDIT:

Based on the comment:

```
select lpad(left(ltrim(medicare), 13), 13, ' ')
```

Comment: thats right but if the input is 12345678901234567 thenI'm getting output as 5678901234567 but the expected output is first 13 characters 1234567890123 @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Vikram . . . Then use `left()` with `trim()` rather than `right()`.